# Why is NoSuchFieldException: ON_STOP thrown on Android 5.0.2?

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I am using **android.arch.lifecycle** extension to detect when the app moves in background or foreground:

```
    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    private void onAppBackgrounded() {
        Log.i(this.getClass().getName(), "onAppBackgrounded()");
    }
```

The extension works fine except on a device running on Android 5.0.2 (SDK 21) on which I get the following exception:

```
Caused by java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: ON_STOP
       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField + 929(Class.java:929)
       at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue + 685(AnnotationAccess.java:685)
       at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance + 663(AnnotationAccess.java:663)
       at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance + 641(AnnotationAccess.java:641)
       at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotation + 170(AnnotationAccess.java:170)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.getAnnotation + 301(Method.java:301)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache.createInfo + 124(ClassesInfoCache.java:124)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.ClassesInfoCache.hasLifecycleMethods + 59(ClassesInfoCache.java:59)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.resolveObserverCallbackType + 137(Lifecycling.java:137)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.getObserverConstructorType + 119(Lifecycling.java:119)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycling.getCallback + 57(Lifecycling.java:57)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.(LifecycleRegistry.java:2)
       at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver + 162(LifecycleRegistry.java:162)
```

Comment: Note that `ProcessLifecycleOwner` is a better solution for your problem ("to detect when the app moves in background or foreground") IMHO. That does not explain this crash, though.